# android studio: Android scrollable gridview with clickable buttons leading to different activities

Tags: android, button, gridview, android-studio, clickable

am creating an android application whereby am required to create a gridview with clickable image buttons each leading to a different activities.Also the gridview should be scrollable since i have many buttons to add .Can anyone help on how to do this? thank you.
Here is a sample of what am trying to do:
[sample clickable gridview:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5S2V.jpg)

Comment: http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-custom-gridview.html check this

Comment: and add click listener for opening activities

Comment: hello can i get the codes of how to add licklistener please..

Comment: Listener are already added in tutorial

Comment: just get the position and open activities according to your need

Answer (score 0):

activitymain.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:numColumns="3" >

    </GridView>

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text=" Computer Languages..." />

</RelativeLayout>
```

programlist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In MainActivity.java

```
 package com.gnetspace.simplegridview;
    import java.util.ArrayList; 
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.GridView;
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        GridView gv;
         Context context;    
            ArrayList prgmName;    
            public static String [] prgmNameList={"Let Us C","c++","JAVA","Jsp","Microsoft .Net","Android","PHP","Jquery","JavaScript"};
        public static int [] prgmImages={R.drawable.images,R.drawable.images1,R.drawable.images2,R.drawable.images3,R.drawable.images4,R.drawable.images5,R.drawable.images6,R.drawable.images7,R.drawable.images8};    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            gv=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);      
            gv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, prgmNameList,prgmImages));
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Create a folder by name drawable in res directory.

```
 public static int [] prgmImages={R.drawable.images,R.drawable.images1,R.drawable.images2,R.drawable.images3,R.drawable.images4,R.drawable.images5,R.drawable.images6,R.drawable.images7,R.drawable.images8};
```

Create CustomAdapter and paste the following code.

```
package com.gnetspace.simplegridview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    String [] result;
    Context context;
 int [] imageId;
      private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList, int[] prgmImages) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        result=prgmNameList;
        context=mainActivity;
        imageId=prgmImages;
         inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                 getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView tv;
        ImageView img;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup      parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;

             rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list, null);
             holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
             holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

         holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
         holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

         rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

the source link is [caveofprograming](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-gridview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html)